# Custom JSON in Apple push notification

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send custom JSON in push notification to apple phone without any additional info.
I would send something like it:

```
{
    message: "Message bla bla"
    , type: 1
    , data: "Tekst" 
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create JSON somewhat like this, if you want parameter also to be passed in it :-

```
{"aps":{"alert":"You got a new message","badge":1,"sound":"beep.wav"},"message":"Message bla bla","type":1,"data":"Tekst"}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Do I have to have my JSON with aps?

Comment: yes, {"aps":{"alert":"You got a new message","badge":1,"sound":"beep.wav"}} is default....

Answer (score 1):

P.J's answer is mostly correct, except for the fact that the `aps` dictionary can be empty, as can be seen in this example (copied from the [APNS Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)) :

> Example 5. The following example shows an empty aps dictionary;
>   because the badge property is missing, any current badge number shown
>   on the application icon is removed. The acme2 custom property is an
>   array of two integers.
>
> {
>
> ```
> "aps" : {
>
> },
>
> "acme2" : [ 5,  8 ]
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }

}
```